# Cascading Dropdown List in InfoPath 2010 with SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, drop-down-menu, infopath, cascadingdropdown, infopath2010

I'm starting on some of my first InfoPath forms. I have a three drop down lists (`Global Function`, `Major Task`, and `Subtask`) which need to query a SQL database and filter their data based on the selected value in the drop down list before it.

**What I've Done So Far**

1. I've already added Data Connections (for each of the tables & corresponding drop down list) which simply query the database for all the records in a table. Each connection is set to "Store a copy of the data in the form template" for Offline Mode.

   Then in the **Drop-Down List Box Properties**, I've set the **List box choices** to "Get choices from an external data source" and setup the **Entries** field to select the columns for the appropriate table / drop-down list combination.

   However, when I add a filter to the data and try to preview the form, the data in the "cascaded" drop down list never changes. It still has ALL of the records.
2. So then I tried to add a new Rule for one of the cascading drop downs. For example, I created a new rule for the `Major Task` drop down and set it up as follows:

   - Condition to `Global Function is not blank`
   - Rule type `Action`
   - Run these actions:
   - Query using a data connection: Major Tasks (which just gets ALL records)

   I don't see anywhere in the Rule / Action to filter the data.
3. **EDIT** I've just tried a new Data Connection which has all three tables (`GlobalFunctions`, `MajorTasks`, and `Subtasks`) that correctly setup the relations (i.e. GlobalFunctions.Id = MajorTasks.GlobalFunction). Then I set the drop down lists' data source to this new connection. However, this too does not filter the data at all. Their entries and values are as follows:

   - Global Function:

     - Entries: `/dfs:myFields/dfs:dataFields/d_1:GlobalFunctions`
     - Filter: `<None>`
     - Value: `@Id`
     - Display name: `@Summary`
   - Major task:

     - Entries: `/dfs:myFields/dfs:dataFields/d_1:GlobalFunctions/d_1:MajorTasks`
     - Filter: `GlobalFunction = Id`
     - Value: `@Id`
     - Display name: `@Summary`
   - Subtask:

     - Entries: `/dfs:myFields/dfs:dataFields/d_1:GlobalFunctions/d_1:MajorTasks/d_1:SubTasks`
     - Filter: `MajorTask = Id`
     - Value: `@Id`
     - Display name: `@Summary`

**Restrictions**

- I can't have any code behind (because it won't work in the browser right?)
- The form must be able to be filled out on the Web or on a local machine (a saved copy on a workstation)
- Should still work when there is no connection to the SQL Database

**Question**

How do I implement multiple cascading drop-down lists in InfoPath 2010 with data connections to a MS SQL Database that can work in the browser and using InfoPath Filler (the latter of which may not have a connection to the database).

**SQL Tables**

Here's what the tables look like:

```
CREATE TABLE GlobalFunctions (
    Id SMALLINT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
    Summary varchar(MAX) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    PRIMARY KEY (Id)
);

CREATE TABLE MajorTasks (
    Id SMALLINT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
    Summary varchar(MAX) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    GlobalFunction SMALLINT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (Id),
    FOREIGN KEY (GlobalFunction) REFERENCES GlobalFunctions(Id)
);

CREATE TABLE SubTasks (
    Id SMALLINT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
    Summary varchar(MAX) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    MajorTask SMALLINT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (Id),
    FOREIGN KEY (MajorTask) REFERENCES SubTasks(Id)
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I found my solution in [this article](http://koobarspoint.blogspot.com/2010/06/cascading-drop-downs-with-infopath-2010.html).

Basically my problem was I was not selecting the correct value (the one that was actually selected) in the previous drop down list when filtering on the current drop down list. Instead, I was selected the value of the option based on the database data.

These are the steps I took to fix my problem (reproduced from the article in case it goes down):

1. Right click the first drop down list and click "**Drop-Down List Properties**" and setup its data source appropriately.
2. Right click the next drop down list to be cascaded and click "**Drop-Down List Properties**".
3. Setup the data source appropriately.
4. Still in the second drop-down list, click the "**Select XPath**" button next to the "Entries" box.
5. Click "**Filter Data**", then Add.
6. In the first drop down box, select "**Select a field or group...**".
7. In the "**Data Source**" drop down list, select "**Main**".
8. Select the "**Global Function**" field, the first in the drop down series (may be under "*myFields*" then "*dataFields*").
9. Set your equality operator in the middle drop down list.
10. In the last drop down, select "**Select a field or group...**".
11. Not changing the data source, under `MajorTasks` select `:GlobalFunction` (the FK relationship to the Global Function table).
12. OK out of all dialogue boxes and repeat for the Subtask drop down list (the last in the series)